# Rails. Creating a User Controller. My Edit method does not show an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, filepath, controllers

I'm creating a app. I've created a User Controller, and successfully created New and Create methods. Running the rails console, I can bring up any ID that I've created. I don't understand when I try to edit from the users/index.html page I'm not directed to /users/id/edit It's just being directed to /users

inspecting the params that are passed, it does show that the correct ID when I click edit for that particular User.

Routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
  users_index GET    /users/index(.:format)    users#index
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)  welcome#index
       macros GET    /macros(.:format)         welcome#macros
         faqs GET    /faqs(.:format)           welcome#faqs
         root GET    /                         welcome#index
        users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
              POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
              PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new

    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(set_user_params)
    if @user.save 
      redirect_to users_path
    else
    end
  end
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  def edit
    raise params.inspect
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end


  private 

    def set_user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :team, :password)
    end
end
```

index.html

```
<div> <%= link_to "Create New Agent", new_user_path %></div>

<% @users.each.with_index(1) do |user, index| %>
    <div class="list_of_agents">
    <%= user.name %><br>
    <%= user.team %><br>
    <%= user.id %><br>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user.id) %><br>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you saying that when `raise params.inspect` is called in the `edit` action, there's no value for `params[:id]`? Or that the `edit` action is never reached?

Answer (score 1):

Please change the `edit` url to

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) %>
```